# how to make a new table from another table with special condition mysql

Tags: mysql-workbench

(this is just dummy data, not real data) i have data buyer like this :

table transaction on January
A 150.000
A 340.000
A 230.000
A 60.000
B 40.000
B 45.000
C 55.000
D. 55.000
A 40.000
D 550.000

so how to make new table from that table where the total of transaction is > 600.000 and after that how to count the average of transaction buyer who the transaction is > 600.000

```
select users_id, total_price_star_member from order_star_member where createdAt >= '2019-12-01' and createdAt < '2020-01-01' group by users_id having sum(total_price_star_member) >= 600000;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this could helps.

```
/* create new table */
Create table new_table as
   Select users_id, total_price_star_member 
   From order_star_member
   Where user_id is null;

/* insert into new table
 * for total transaction greater or equal 600,000
 */
Insert into new_table (user_id, total_price_star_member)
   Select user_id, total_price_star_member
   From order_star_member
   Where user_id in (
      Select users_id
      From order_star_member
      Where createdAt >= '2019-12-01'
        and createdAt < '2020-01-01'
      Group by users_id
      Having sum(total_price_star_member) >= 600000);

/* select average transaction
 * for buyers that have total transactions
 * greater or equal 600,000
 */
Select avg(total_price_star_member) as avg_total_price_star_member
From new_table;
```

Cheers!